# Woman doctor or lady doctor?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Say, somebody wants to visit a doctor who is a woman or a doctor who is specialist in treating women. I wonder if there are specific terms for

> (a) A doctor who is a woman
>
> (b) A doctor who treats only women

Three terms ring in my mind: *woman doctor*, *lady doctor*, and *women doctor*.
Although ngram results show “woman doctor” overtook “lady doctor” in early twentieth century, I am confused as to what it means (a or b).

Comment: 'Man doctor' is a virtually unknown expression compared to female/woman/male doctor. [Ngram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=man+doctor%2C+male+doctor%2C+woman+doctor%2C+female+doctor&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cman%20doctor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmale%20doctor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwoman%20doctor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfemale%20doctor%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @NigelJ - that because by culture, tradition, custom and policy, doctors have always been men, from time immemorial.

Answer (score 4):

Collins Dictionary cites ***[woman doctor](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/woman-doctor)*** meaning:

> a female doctor: *A woman doctor examined me*.

and defines ***[lady doctor](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lady-doctor)*** as old-fashioned:

> - (old-fashioned)
>     a doctor who is a female

Not to be confused with     ***[woman's doctor](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/woman%27s+doctor)***

> - a specialist in gynecologywoman's doctor - a specialist in gynecology

I'd personally use "female doctor".

> - [The Study That Said Female Doctors Are Better Than Male Doctors](https://www.forbes.com/sites/brucelee/2017/02/04/the-study-that-said-female-doctors-are-better-than-male-doctors/#59444f613f92)

Comment: But is a female doctor (a) or (b)? That's the whole crux of the question and you've missed it out!

Comment: @AndyT - a female doctor is a woman doctor as clearly reported in the answer. See Collins definition.

Comment: "A female doctor is a woman doctor because a woman doctor is a female doctor". Great.... but are they a doctor who is a woman or a doctor who treats women?

Comment: @AndyT - a "***female, woman, lady doctor***" is a doctor who is a woman.  A "***woman's doctor***" is either a male or a female doctor who treats women.

Comment: @AndyT - A doctor who treats women is a *doctor*.

Comment: The days of calling doctors "lady/woman/female doctors" are thankfully long gone. Just like "male nurses" used to be quite popular, nowadays there is no distinction between the sexes, and you should mention this in your answer.

Comment: @user2922582 - I think you are missing my point. The OP asks for both "a doctor who is a woman" and "a doctor who treats only women". Your answer concludes with "I'd personally use female doctor" - *but you don't say which for*. Yes "female" can be an adjective, but it can also be a noun. Hence in "female doctor" the "female" might be either an adjective or a noun adjunct. Compare "[horse doctor](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/horse-doctor)" where "horse" is used as a noun adjunct.

Comment: It is grammatically valid to interpret "female doctor" as a doctor for females. But it isn't idiomatic. Your answer should make that clear. Please note that I don't think your answer is "wrong" as such, and hence I have no interest in posting a competing answer; I just don't think your answer is sufficiently *clear*.

Comment: @AndyT - I really don't understand your point.  My answer, if you read it,   refers to both a and b. Female doctor, as per the example  shown, refers to woman doctor , "***female doctors*** are better than ***male doctor***". if you thinkit is unclear just post your own answer please.